# Resizing of axes when plotting in the same figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Please, create two functions to be able to reproduce what I mean:

First function:

```
function testPlot1()

pointData = rand(20000,3);
figure;
%hold on;  % <- if commented out, does not work
plot3(pointData(:,1), pointData(:,2), pointData(:,3),'Marker', '.', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'b','MarkerSize', 5, 'LineStyle', 'none');

axis equal;
xh = xlabel('X');
yh = ylabel('Y');
zh = zlabel('Z');
set([xh,yh, zh],...
    'fontweight','bold',...
    'fontsize',14,...
    'color',[0,0,0]);
view(0,20);

end
```

Second function:

```
function testPlot2(fighandle)
axes(fighandle);
hold on;
plot3([0 3],[0 3],[0 3], 'r', 'LineWidth', 10);
end
```

If you now call

```
testPlot1();testPlot2(gca)
```

you will get the following:
[image]

If you however uncomment the "hold on" line in testPlot1() and call the above statement again, you will get:

[image]

To me this is unclear behavior. In the first case, testPlot1() creates a figure, draws the point cloud into it and modifies the axes properties. Then the call to testPlot2(gca) adds the line to the figure, but the line is clipped. 
In the second case however the line is not clipped anymore. Why is it now not clipped and previously it was?

It seems to be related to the changes I make in the axes properties in testPlot1(). Could somebody explain this behavior to me? (why does it work with hold on, what do my changes in the axes properties cause)

Comment: Is this a typo: "(why does it work with hold on, ..." It **doesn't** work with `hold on`, isn't that what you are asking?

Comment: No, not a typo. I will make an edit anyway, because it is a bit confusing like this. The first time I call testPlot1();testPlot2(gca) is when "hold on" is commented out.I will also try and clarify my confusion a bit

Answer (score 0):

`hold on` is a Matlab command (`hold off` turns it off again), where you can draw multiple elements on a single figure without the previous elements being erased.

## What happens

If you call the `plot` function, a figure is created (or an already exisiting figure is used!) and Matlab draws a *new* plot into that figure. The previous plot that was in that figure is gone.

If you want to add more points to your plot, you can call `hold on` and then call `plot` again, this time with different numbers and maybe a different colour or so.
**However**, if you forget to turn `hold off` again for the active figure, any drawing activity you do (like `plot`) will be added to the figure. This is what happens in your second image in your question. You drew some points in the range 0 to 1, and then in the second function, you add some more but in the range 2 to 3. As a result, the axes expand to the range of 0 to 3.

*Alternatively*, you can call `figure`, which will cause a new figure to appear. `figure_handle = figure();`  will return a figure handle, which you can pass to your function, in case you have multiple figures and want to change one of them after a while.

Comment: I know, but the issue above is the resizing of the axes limits. In the first case both is drawn in the same figure as well, the "line" is just not visible because its clipped

Comment: What do you expect to see with the `hold on` in `function1`? I wouldn't want to have it there in the first place, but what it does is completely expected.

Comment: If my comment doesn't make sense, that's because user1809923 changed his/her comment...